# Why do I need "--expose" option in Docker?

Tags: docker

I am confused about the "--expose" option in Docker, I do not know what it will actually do.

When I specify it (e.g., --expose=1234) in "docker run ...", where will the port will be EXPOSED? I do not think I can access the port in the host, if I want that, I think what I need is "-p", so what "--expose" will actually do?

I think if I want to access a container port from the host, what I need is, let the service in the container listen on the port, use "-p" option in "docker run" to publish the port on the host. Or in this case, I still have to use "--expose" to expose the port?

Comment: What did your testing show? Does `-p` do what you want? The two [options are for different directions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports), inbound and outbound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-p` will allows you to map an already EXPOSE'd port (as set in the Dockerfile).

But if that port was not EXPOSE'd in the Dockerfile and its resulting image, you can still expose it with `--expose`:

From [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports):

> The `EXPOSE` instruction defines the initial incoming ports that provide services. These ports are available to processes inside the container. An operator can use the `--expose` option to add to the exposed ports.

That is a way to overwrite the image definition (which did not expose a port) by exposing that port at runtime.
Actually "overwrite" is the wrong term, as mentioned in [PR 14625](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14625) and [PR 15675](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15675):

> With the exception of the `EXPOSE` directive, an image developer hasn't
>   got much control over networking. The `EXPOSE` instruction defines the
>   initial incoming ports that provide services. These ports are available
>   processes inside the container.
>   An operator can use **the `--expose` option to add to the exposed ports**.

("add" is key here: you can declare at runtime *additional* ports)

As I mention in the comments, this has nothing to do with the activity on the `EXPOSE` port (it does not guarantee that a process is listening to the port within the container)
It is just a way to declare an [**open port**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_port), that is a port which will accept packets.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean even the service running in the container listens on a port, if I do not expose it by EXPOSE or "--expose", I can NOT publish that port by "-p" in the host? I.e., EXPOSE or "--expose" is the precondition of "-p"?

Comment: @Eric yes, that is the idea. EXPOSE allows for other containers to access that port (or for the user to map said port to the host port). No EXPOSE means the port is invisible outside the container.

Comment: but it needs container to be cooperative, right? I mean, what if a port is exposed by EXPOSE or "--expose" but the service running in the container actually does not listen on that port? Is there a mechanism to guarantee the exposed port is indeed listened inside the container?

Comment: @Eric No, both issue (expose and listen) are completely separate. EXPOSE means another container (or the host if mapped) can query the port. But if nobody listen to that port, you will get no answer. EXPOSE is not there to guarantee anything regarding how that port is managed. It is just there to open it to the outside world.

Comment: @ So it seems what EXPOSE does is only claiming the exposed port no matter the port is actually being listened or not, that means it may deliver wrong message to outside, e.g., a port is exposed by EXPOSE or "--expose" but it is not actually being listened by anyone inside the container.
And another question is, can I publish (-p) a port which is not exposed by EXPOSE or "--expose"?

Comment: @Eric yes, this has nothing to do with listening. It is a just way to declare an open port (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_port): that port will now accept packets. That is all.

Comment: @Eric -p is for mapping an EXPOSEd port. If the port was not exposed in the first place, the publish will fail.

Comment: @Eric No problem. I have included some of those comments, with additional links, in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC When publishing a port (-p) docker implicitly exposes a port that is published; see this for more info https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/docker-networking-rules/.

Comment: So the real question still remains, why do we need an `--expose` option?

Comment: @SaadMalik I suppose only if you want to add exposed port (but *not* publish them)

Comment: @VonC still seems weird though, ya? I can understand the `EXPOSE` statement in Dockerfile, but what's the point of exposing ports with the `run` command?  

For kicks and giggle with `docker run -it -P --expose 1234 alpine sh` docker does publish `1234`, but it's much more intuitive to type `docker run -it -p 1234 alpine sh`

Comment: @SaadMalik no: exposing without publishing makes sense: it allows another container to access your exposed port, while preventing any user to access the same port (because it was not published). Hence the need for `--expose`.

Comment: So I tested with two simple alpine containers and found that even non-exposed ports are accessible from another container, however, when linking (`--link`) the exposed ports are available as environment variables.